# Submit two forms from 1a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to have one view with 2 forms in it and submit both forms at the same time?

I don't want to use nested forms.

For example:

I have :

```
Model Survey
|_question_id
|_answers_id 

Model Question:
|_text

Model Answer
|_text
```

Is it possible to do that without nested forms? For example I want to create a NEW question (Form 1) and a NEW answer (Form 2) and in the create method in the Controller I will create a new Survey and **MANUALLY** assign the question_id and answers_id to the newly created question and answer accordingly!

Thanks

Comment: You can have two forms in a view and submit them independently of each other, I am not sure how would submitting them at the same time would go though.

Comment: What I mean is if, you are using ajax for the independent submits than it would be fine, and you can wait for response for both the form submissions. I am still skeptical about relating question and answer though. With http submits, I can't wrap around my head at the idea of submitting two requests at once. May be the first request would be just ignored by client. May be client will respond to whatever response comes first. But, whatever happens, there is a lot of bad smell there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better approach would be to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to build all three models via one form submission.

Set your models up like so:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :question
  has_many :answers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :question, :answers
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
end
```

Then you can write your form using rails helpers like this:

```
<%= form_for @survey do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :question do |question_form| %>
   <%= question_form.text_field :question
  <% end %>
  <%= form.fields_for :answers do |answer_form| %>
   <%= question_form.text_field :answer
  <% end %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In the controller action that will render the form you need to build the new records in memory like this:

```
class SurveyController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
    @survey.build_question
    @survey.answers.build
  end
end
```

You can read more about `accepts_nested_attributes_for here`: http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes

Comment: If one of the models has has_many instead of has_one. Will this require any changes?